# Cardinality of a dense open set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In a compact space of cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$, can a dense open subset be countable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dense open subset of a compact space of cardinality $2^{2^\omega}$ can even be countable: an example is $\beta\Bbb N$ (or $\beta\omega$, if you prefer), the Čech-Stone compactification of the natural numbers. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149563/12042) to an earlier question shows that $2^{2^\omega}$ is the maximum possible cardinality of a separable Hausdorff space, and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83540/12042) shows that $|\beta\Bbb N|=2^{2^\omega}$.

**Added:** An example of cardinality $2^\omega$ can be built in $\Bbb R^2$ as follows. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $$D_n=\left\{\left\langle\frac{2k+1}{2^n},\frac1{2^n}\right\rangle:k=0,\dots,2^{n-1}-1\right\}\;,$$ and let $$D=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}D_n\;.$$ Let $X=D\cup[0,1]$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ with the usual topology. Then $D$ is a countable dense set of isolated points in $X$, which is compact and of cardinality $2^\omega$.

Comment: A nitpick: does this really answer the question? It's not quite obvious how to cut down the size from $2^{2^{\omega}}$ to $2^{\omega}$, so a priori it *might* still be the case that a situation as in the question can't occur. A natural example would be the geometric compactification by adding $S^1$ to an orbit of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ acting on  the Poincaré disk.

Comment: @t.b.: It doesn’t literally answer the question; I’m still thinking about that. But since the question may have been a stand-in for ‘How large can such a space be?’, I thought it worth posting.

Answer (score 1):

Another example: Consider the homeomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n \to B_{1}(0)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the open unit ball $B_1(0)$ given by $\varphi(x) = \frac{x}{1+\|x\|}$ and let $X$ be the closure of $\varphi(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ in the closed unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $X = \varphi(\mathbb{Z}^n) \cup S^{n-1}$ is compact, and assuming $n \geq 2$ it has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. Moreover, $\varphi(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ is countable, open and dense in $X$.

Comment: One good nitpick deserves another: you need to specify that $n\ge 2$: if $n=1$, $X$ is just a double-ended sequence. (Basically the same trick that I ended up using.)

Comment: Okay, you win! Fixed, thanks :)

Comment: We could continue the nitpicking and observe that Hausdorff wasn't specified, so take a cofinite set in a countable space with the cofinite topology...

Comment: Hey, no one said anything about $T_0$; why not start with $\omega+1$ and blow up the limit point to an undifferentiated lump of ... oh, say measurable cardinality? :-)

Comment: Oh, great! :) At least this example works (if you don't blow the lump up to be too large so as to guarantee $2^{\aleph_0}$ cardinality), contrary to mine...