Every separable metric space has cardinality less or equal than the cardinality of continuum

Every separable metric space $E$ has cardinality less or equal than the cardinality of continuum.

As $E$ is Hausdorff; $\{x\}$ is closed, so $E-\{x\}$ is open in $E$; as $E$ is second-countable (let $(B_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the countable basis) , then $E-\{x \}= \bigcup_{j \in J_x \subset \mathbb{N}}B_j$
Consider the mapping:
\begin{align*}
\varphi:\ &E \mapsto \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\\
              &x \longrightarrow J_x
\end{align*}
Then, if $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y) \implies J_x=J_y \implies \{x\}=\{y\}$; so, $\varphi$ is one-to-one and $|E| \leq 2^{|\mathbb{N}|}$.
Is this a valid argument? Should I use the separability as well?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723948/how-big-can-a-separable-hausdorff-space-be#:~:text=The%20maximum%20possible%20cardinality%20of,is%2022%E2%84%B50.

You use separability when you say it's 2nd countable.

Simpler (also doesn't require knowing separability is same as 2nd countability for metric spaces) is to note that, for a given countable dense subset, there are at most continuum many sequences, all of whose terms belong to that subset, because ${\aleph_0}^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c.$ Incidentally, if the countable dense subset is actually finite, but at least $2,$ then still get $\mathfrak c.$ Now note that there cannot be MORE (in the sense of cardinality) elements in the metric space than there are sequences of this type.

Yes, your proof is correct. In fact, you have shown, that every second-countable $T_1$ space has cardinality less than or equal to continuum size. This implies the mentioned statement, since separable metric spaces are second-countable, but covers many more spaces.
